# Is it possible to use multiple active vertex colors?

Tags: interface, vertex-colors

I'm using vertex colors to control features of a material. This works well for one of them, but I'm out of channels and need to handle pigmentation now.

The other option is of course using a texture, but that would be mildly more complicated for me here.

I know that I can add additional vertex color sets, but as of yet, only one of them is active at a time (even though I'm selecting the other vertex color set in my Vertex Color node). Having one active makes the other invisible, which I can understand, but muting it in a material surprises me. It very much limits what can be done with vertex colors.

I've tried shift+clicking and control+clicking to no avail. Can more than one vertex color group be concurrently used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use that attribute node in the shader editor. Type the attribute in the field at the bottom to access the channel you want.

[image]
[image]